# How to set Material-UI icon for a form field ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to know how can I set an `icon` in front of the `select` field. I have already done this for `TextField` as below

```
<TextField
id="input-with-icon-textfield"
label="Env.Satisfaction"
InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position="start">
        <SentimentSatisfied />
    </InputAdornment>
    ),
}}
/>
```

But I tried this with `select` and it didn't work:

```
<Select
labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
id="demo-simple-select"
value={age}
onChange={handleChange}
InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment position="start">
        <SupervisedUserCircle />
        </InputAdornment>
    ),
    }}
>
<MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Can someone please help me?

This is how it looks in a `TextField`, I want to do this for `Select` as well.

[TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whXgV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches,

First one is using the Select component

```
<Select
   labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
   id="demo-simple-select"
   value={currency}
   onChange={handleChange}
   startAdornment={
    <InputAdornment position="start">
      <AccountCircle />
    </InputAdornment>
    }
   >
  {currencies.map(option => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
       {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

the second approach is using the Text field,

```
<TextField
  id="standard-select-currency"
  select
  label="Select"
  value={currency}
  onChange={handleChange}
  helperText="Please select your currency"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
         <AccountCircle />
      </InputAdornment>
     )
  }}
  >
   {currencies.map(option => (
     <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
     </MenuItem>
   ))}
</TextField>
```

find a working example I created here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8qxtv